# D lang simple benchmarking

Tags: java, benchmarking, d

I'm new in D and I'm comparing it vs Java in simple tests and expecting to see that the native language will be faster (or roughly the same). But it in my first test with recursion D is surprisingly slower than Java (almost two times).

Java (this is bad java perfomance test but it just simple idea):

```
public static void main(String... args) {
        long before = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println(fibonacci(40));
        System.out.println(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(System.nanoTime() - before));
    }

    static int fibonacci(int n) {
        if (n < 2) {
            return n;
        }
        return fibonacci(n - 2) + fibonacci(n - 1);
    }
```

Environment: Win7 64bit, JDK: 1.7.0_10 x64.

D:

```
import std.stdio;
import std.datetime;

void main(string[] args)
{
    auto r = benchmark!(simplebench)(1);
    writefln("%s", r[0].to!("msecs", int));
}

void simplebench() {
    writeln(fibonacci(40));
}

int fibonacci(int n) {
    if (n < 2) {
        return n;
    }
    return fibonacci(n - 2) + fibonacci(n - 1);
}
```

Environment: Win7 64bit, dmd 2.061, compiler options: -noboundscheck -inline -O -release

Java ~570ms and D ~1011ms.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: a) Java is quite good at arithmetic, b) perhaps the D compiler just isn't so good?

Comment: I hope you chose that implementation because it isn't optimial...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Java is also native via its JIT compiler. If you disable the JIT using `-Xint` (forces interpreter) then you'll see that D is significantly faster. For what it's worth, I tried a similar implementation in C and got the same speed as in D.

These sorts of micro benchmarks are not useful for testing general performance. All you are doing here is testing Java JIT compiled code versus D compiled code. They're both being compiled. Also, this is not typical Java code. Typical Java programs allocates a lot of memory on the heap, whereas typical D programs do not.

If you want to learn about *real* performance of D versus Java then you need you test it on *real* programs.

Comment: also ensure that you are actually testing the same program

Answer (score 8):

DMD is the reference compiler for D, however its backend doesn't produce code as fast as the other compilers, GDC and LDC, as CyberShadow mentioned earlier.

Timings measured on my computer:

D compilers, all using the following flags or their equivalents:  -noboundscheck -inline -O -release

DMD   ~905ms,
LDC   ~663ms,
GDC   ~382ms

Java  ~445ms

g++   ~370ms under -O3

These (micro-)results show that the D code is as performant as the cpp equivalent when compiled using the same backends, and that it is faster than the Java code.

Answer (score 2):

DMD's backend doesn't optimize as well as the GCC-based [GDC](http://gdcproject.org/) or the LLVM-based [LDC](https://github.com/ldc-developers/ldc). Your test program runs slightly faster for me than Java when built with GDC. If performance is important for your project, don't use DMD for release builds.

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing anything wrong. Java's JIT is very good and probably optimises certain code better than the, let me guess, the DMD compiler? - Try the GDC or LDC compilers and see what kind of results does the testing of produced executables give. I would also test LuaJIT as well, and I would expect it to be extremely fast with these small algorithms that deal with PODs.